# Perl script fails from crontab but not command line

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that is designed to connect to an MS SQL server DB.  It uses DBI module.

For some reason I can execute the script from the command line and it works fine but when I put it into a Crontab it fails with this error:

> DBI object version 1.627 does not match bootstrap parameter 1.643 at
> /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 213. BEGIN failed--compilation
> aborted at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/DBI.pm line 284. Compilation failed
> in require at /app/www/tools/GoSet/art_db_insert.pl line 5.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
> /app/www/tools/GoSet/art_db_insert.pl line 5.

I've verified that my 'which perl' matches the shebang line in the script.
I also verified that if I do 'perldoc -m DBI' it shows the version 1.643.
I cant figure out where it is getting the version 1.627 from or why it works from command line but not crontab.

I have other perl scripts in crontab that work fine, but this is the only one with an error (and the only one using DBI).

Any ideas?

crontab line:

```
19 6-17 * * 1-5 cd /app/www/tools/GoSet&& perl /app/www/tools/GoSet/art_db_insert.pl > /app/www/tools/GoSet/artcron.log 2>&1
```

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'
   say "INC:"; say "  $_" for @INC;
   say "ENV:"; say "  $_: $ENV{$_}" for sort grep /^PERL/, keys %ENV;
'
INC:
  /usr/local/lib64/perl5
  /usr/local/share/perl5
  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
  /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
  /usr/lib64/perl5
  /usr/share/perl5
  .
ENV:
```

Comment: What's the output of `perl -M5.010 -e'say for @INC; say "--"; say "$_: $ENV{$_}" for sort grep /^PERL/ keys %ENV;'`? Best guess: You set `PERL5LIB` in your shell environment, but not in the cron environment

Comment: crontab line 19 6-17 * * 1-5 cd /app/www/tools/GoSet&& perl /app/www/tools/GoSet/art_db_insert.pl > /app/www/tools/GoSet/artcron.log 2>&1

Comment: ikegami, that command doesnt execute, it claims there are missing parameters for grep.
I do have other perl scripts running in this cron but this is the only one using DBI.  How would I verify if the environment has the right info?

Comment: Missing comma after `grep /^PERL/` (Make sure to use `@ikegami` so I get notified)

Comment: @ikegami I get this:

/usr/local/lib64/perl5
/usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
.
--

How do I set the environment I need for this particular script?  I would have thought that since others work, this one should.

Comment: Are both processes running as the same user? When it works, is the work directory `/app/www/tools/GoSet` like in the cron job?

Comment: Run `env` in your shell and paste all those into a new `#!/bin/bash`  wrapper script. Might need export, like `export VAR=value`, in front of them. Also paste the original crontab command at the end of the wrapper script and run that  script as the new crontab command. This way you have all your shell environment variables in your cron job that you have in your shell. If it works now you can remove env vars one by one from the new script to see which you need and which you don't.

Comment: @Kjetil S. That won't help. The shell doesn't have any relevant env vars set

Comment: @ikegami I can run the script from any directory when done from the command line, it seems to work regardless. i.e.  just put "/app/www/tools/GoSet/art_db_insert.pl" into the command line and hit enter.  When I run it from the command line it is run as me /w sudo.  When it runs in cron it runs under a different user that doesnt have sudo but is the owner of the directory/file.  (and can run the other perl scripts that dont use DBI)

Comment: Best guess is a difference in file permissions for the installed modules or the directories in their path (in fact, only guess I have right now

Comment: @ikegami I checked permissions of a perl module that is working in another script (Net::Telnet) vs the DBI module and they are the same.  They arent installed in the same path, but both paths are in the INC list.  Directories in both paths have the same permissions as well.

Comment: `locate DBI.pm` run as root might turn up some hints about the various versions of DBI installed on your system. Also, run @ikegami's command from the relevant crontab and see if that turns up any differences in the environment.

Comment: ... and DBI.so.

Comment: @ikegami believe I have got it working. I found another copy of DBI.pm farther into the file paths I had checked previously. It was apparently using that one instead of the one farther up for some reason.  I corrected the permissions and it ran without error.

Comment: That was obvious from the start. But having two installs of DBI on a machine isn't a problem. The real problem is the difference that causes the two processes to find different things.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `perl path/to/yourscript.pl`, the shebang line is ignored. To have the script run by the interpreter defined in the shebang line, it must be made executable (`chmod +x`) and then invoked as `./yourscript.pl` or `path/to/yourscript.pl`.

When the file is passed as positional parameter to the binary, the shebang line is simply parsed as a regular comment and has no effect.